# opengl Color & Cube is not working properly

Tags: opengl, glut

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>

    #include<GL/glut.h>

    double cameraAngle;

    void grid_and_axes() {

        // draw the three major AXES

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        //X axis
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0); //100% Green
        glVertex3f(-150, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(150, 0, 0);

        //Y axis
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1); //100% Blue
        glVertex3f(0, -150, 0); // intentionally extended to -150 to 150, no big deal
        glVertex3f(0, 150, 0);

        //Z axis
        glColor3f(1, 1, 1); //100% White
        glVertex3f(0, 0, -150);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 150);
        glEnd();

        //some gridlines along the field
        int i;

        glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);   //grey
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        for (i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {

            if (i == 0)
                continue;   //SKIP the MAIN axes

                            //lines parallel to Y-axis
            glVertex3f(i * 10, -100, 0);
            glVertex3f(i * 10, 100, 0);

            //lines parallel to X-axis
            glVertex3f(-100, i * 10, 0);
            glVertex3f(100, i * 10, 0);
        }
        glEnd();

    }

    void display() {
        //codes for Models, Camera

        //clear the display
        //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);   //color black
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     //clear buffers to preset values

                                                                /***************************
                                                                / set-up camera (view) here
                                                                ****************************/
                                                                //load the correct matrix -- MODEL-VIEW matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     //specify which matrix is the current matrix

                                        //initialize the matrix
        glLoadIdentity();               //replace the current matrix with the identity matrix [Diagonals have 1, others have 0]

                                        //now give three info
                                        //1. where is the camera (viewer)?
                                        //2. where is the camera looking?
                                        //3. Which direction is the camera's UP direction?

                                        //gluLookAt(0,-150,20,  0,0,0,  0,0,1);
        gluLookAt(150 * sin(cameraAngle), -150 * cos(cameraAngle), 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);


        /*************************
        / Grid and axes Lines
        **************************/
        grid_and_axes();


        /****************************
        / Add your objects from here
        ****************************/

        /*glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glutSolidCone(20, 20, 20, 20);

        glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        GLUquadricObj *cyl = gluNewQuadric();
        gluCylinder(cyl, 10, 10, 50, 20, 20);

        glTranslatef(0, 0, 50);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glutSolidCone(10, 20, 20, 20);
    */
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

        glutSolidCube(1);
```

> I am not getting any cube here.
>   However if I use any transformation property like scaling or rotate then I get the desired cube like
>   glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
>   glScalef(50,5,60);
>   glutSolidCube(1);
>   what is the problem?
>   Another problem I am facing that color doesn't work if i don't use transformation property like above mentioned. If I write:
>   glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
>   glutSolidCone(20, 20, 20, 20);
>   For above codes color doesn't work; i get the default colored cone
>   However if I change this two lines to these 3 lines then color works perfectly:
>   glColor3f(1,0,0);
>   glTranslatef(0, 0, 50);
>   glutSolidCone(10,20,20,20);
>   then color works; what is the problem?  Please help

```
        //ADD this line in the end --- if you use double buffer (i.e. GL_DOUBLE)
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    void animate() {
        //codes for any changes in Models, Camera

        cameraAngle += 0.001;   // camera will rotate at 0.002 radians per frame.

                                //codes for any changes in Models

                                //MISSING SOMETHING? -- YES: add the following
        glutPostRedisplay();    //this will call the display AGAIN

    }

    void init() {
        //codes for initialization

        cameraAngle = 0;    //angle in radian
                            //clear the screen
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

        /************************
        / set-up projection here
        ************************/
        //load the PROJECTION matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

        //initialize the matrix
        glLoadIdentity();

        /*
        gluPerspective() — set up a perspective projection matrix

        fovy -         Specifies the field of view angle, in degrees, in the y direction.
        aspect ratio - Specifies the aspect ratio that determines the field of view in the x direction. The aspect ratio is the ratio of x (width) to y (height).
        zNear -        Specifies the distance from the viewer to the near clipping plane (always positive).
        zFar  -        Specifies the distance from the viewer to the far clipping plane (always positive).
        */

        gluPerspective(70, 1, 0.1, 10000.0);

    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        glutInit(&argc, argv);                          //initialize the GLUT library

        glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
```

/*
            glutInitDisplayMode - inits display mode
            GLUT_DOUBLE - allows for display on the double buffer window
            GLUT_RGBA - shows color (Red, green, blue) and an alpha
            GLUT_DEPTH - allows for depth buffer
            */
            glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);

```
        glutCreateWindow("Some Title");

        init();                     //codes for initialization

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    //enable Depth Testing

        glutDisplayFunc(display);   //display callback function
        glutIdleFunc(animate);      //what you want to do in the idle time (when no drawing is occuring)

        glutMainLoop();     //The main loop of OpenGL

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't read your question, but please, use modern OpenGL. There are many old tutorials out there. https://learnopengl.com is one of the best websites I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not getting any cube here.

You *do* get a cube. It is just that tiny speck where the axis intersect. What else would you expect to see when you draw something 2 units big, ~160 units away, with a 70 degree field of view?

> Another problem I am facing that color doesn't work if i don't use transformation property like above mentioned.
>   [...] I get the default colored cone.

I've no idea what you even mean by that. The "default color" would be the initial value of GL's builtin color attribute - which is `(1, 1, 1, 1)` - white. With the code you have set up, you will get the color which you set before. So the only guess I can make here is that you confused yourself by not properly taking GL's state machine into account.

But besides all that, you should not use that code at all - this is using the fixed function pipeline and immediate mode drawing - features which are *deprecated* since a decade now, and *not supported* at all by modern core profiles of OpenGL. Trying to learn that stuff in 2017 is a waste of time. And btw:

> ```
> glutMainLoop();     //The main loop of OpenGL
> ```

Nope. Just **NO!!!**. OpenGL does not have a "main loop". GLUT is not OpenGL. Honestly, this is all just horrible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.This is a template provided by my university faculty of Computer Graphics course.The platform and coding he is teaching in the course just going over my head! The matter of pain is that I am not having any tutorials exactly matched with the approach of my faculty. You are also telling this is horrible :'( i really don't know what to do as there is no way of dropping the course out.

Comment: Well, I don't know what your issue exactly is. I did explain why you didn't see the cube without the scaling. And if have no idea what the problem is with the color of the cone - I did try out the actual code from your question, and everything just appears as it should. And as far as the university graphics courses go: yes, there lots of these which teach 20 year old OpenGL. Yes, there is typically not much you can do against it, but that doesn't change the fact that it is just horrible.